# WebStorm shows warnings for objects, types and directives in Angular, but they work correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, webstorm, typescript-eslint

**WebStorm shows warnings for objects, types and directives in Angular Template Html, but they work correctly**

In Angular within WebStorm, there are warnings being displayed for types and Angular directives all html structured functionality and definitions, even though they are functioning correctly without any issues. They all works Fine but i have warns anyway.

I restarted the TypeScript services in the bottom bar and repaired the IDE from the 'File' menu, but none of these resolved my issue. Have you ever encountered this before?

**Current Versions I have:**

```text
WebStorm 2022.3.1,
Build #WS-223.8214.51,
built on December 20, 2022,
For educational use only,
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 amd64,
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

```text
"@angular/cdk": "^16.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "~16.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.2",
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Please **always** state your versions (IDE version at very least; Angular etc). The issue might be resolved in the current version (in case you are using older one) or in the next major version. 2) Also show what the actual error/warning is (hover over the error and show what popup will show). This will also give some context (maybe it comes not from the IDE core but from one of the tools etc)

Comment: I still see no details about the error. Anyway -- *"WebStorm 2022.3.1,"* -- if this is about `*ngIf` (it is highlighted on your screenshot) then please upgrade to the latest major version **2023.1** (latest is 2023.1.4) -- it should work there. **P.S.** The next major 2023.2 is about to be released soon (a few weeks time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely solved my problem by installing WebStorm version **2023.1.4**